# Subset Data Using Two Variables and Summarize it

Tags: r, subset, reshape2

I have a data.frame with 3 columns. I have many different "strains" with many different "TE" matched with their frequency. What I want to do is for each TE know how many strains are in the same range for a given TEfrequency value.

```
dt <- as.data.table(read.table(header=TRUE,text="     strain   TE      TEfrequency
    1 S1 FBti0015567    0.000000
    2 S2 FBti0015567    0.000000
    3 S3 FBti0015567   42.857143
    4 S1 FBti0018865   25.000000
    5 S2 FBti0018865    3.225806
    6 S3 FBti0018865   33.333333"))



> head(dt)
     strain   TE      TEfrequency
    1 S1 FBti0015567    0.000000
    2 S2 FBti0015567    0.000000
    3 S3 FBti0015567   42.857143
    4 S1 FBti0018865   25.000000
    5 S2 FBti0018865    3.225806
    6 S3 FBti0018865   33.333333
```

For example in this dummy dataset for FBti0015567

if I want to query for frequencies lower than 10% I would get a 2 for  FBti0015567 (S1 + S2) and 1 for FBti0018865 (S2).

```
TE num_strains 
FBti0015567 2
FBti0018865 1
```

For a query of >20%

```
TE num_strains 
FBti0015567 1
FBti0018865 2
```

My naive approach is to make a subset for each combination of values but this is unfeasible because I have more than 40 strains and more than 1400 TE's.
Is there an easy way to obtain a table summarizing this information by TE with an input frequency interval?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide a small sample dataset and the expected outcome for the example table you have already provided?

Comment: I've borrowed the code for the dataset from MikeyMike and added some output examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm interpreting the question correctly, you want for each TE & TEfrequency combination the number of unique strains. Data.table is awesome and you can do this in 1 step if you want.

```
library(data.table)

dt <- as.data.table(read.table(header=TRUE,text="     strain   TE      TEfrequency
    1 S1 FBti0015567    0.000000
    2 S2 FBti0015567    0.000000
    3 S3 FBti0015567   42.857143
    4 S1 FBti0018865   25.000000
    5 S2 FBti0018865    3.225806
    6 S3 FBti0018865   33.333333"))

dt[,list(count_uniq_strain=length(unique(strain))),by=list(TE,TEfrequency)][TEfrequency < 10]

            TE TEfrequency count_uniq_strain
1: FBti0015567    0.000000                 2
2: FBti0018865    3.225806                 1
```

I'm assuming that "filtering by frequencies lower than 10%" you mean dropping observations with TEfrequency < 10.

*Edit:* Adding a query function:

```
dt2<-dt[,list(count_uniq_strain=length(unique(strain))),by=list(TE,TEfrequency)]

query <- function(inds,condition){
  return(inds[eval(parse(text=condition))])   
}

filter_gt_20 <- query(inds=dt2,condition="TEfrequency > 20")
filter_lt_10 <- query(inds=dt2,condition="TEfrequency < 10")


> filter_gt_20
            TE TEfrequency count_uniq_strain
1: FBti0015567    42.85714                 1
2: FBti0018865    25.00000                 1
3: FBti0018865    33.33333                 1
> filter_lt_10
            TE TEfrequency count_uniq_strain
1: FBti0015567    0.000000                 2
2: FBti0018865    3.225806                 1
```

Comment: It's almost what I want. I've updated the question to better explain myself with 2 examples. When I say filter by I mean give an input range of frequencies.

Comment: You can easily change the `TEfrequency < 10` to `TEfrequency > 20` if you want. Or you can completely get rid of the `TEfrequency < 10` code and save the data table then filter based on whatever you want. That way you only have to do 1 summary.

Comment: Apparently it doesn't put them together

> subset(filter_lt_10, TE=='FBti0015567')
            TE TEfrequency count_uniq_strain
1: FBti0015567    0.000000                34
2: FBti0015567    4.000000                 1
3: FBti0015567    5.263158                 2
4: FBti0015567    9.090909                 3
5: FBti0015567    2.500000                 1
6: FBti0015567    3.333333                 2
7: FBti0015567    6.060606                 1
8: FBti0015567    5.154639                 1

They should be only one TE and one count for the given frequency. Maybe we can use aggregate¿?

Comment: It works for me. I get `> subset(filter_lt_10, TE=='FBti0015567')
            TE TEfrequency count_uniq_strain
1: FBti0015567           0                 2`

Comment: For the small example it works (both have the SAME frequency). What happens is that when we have many different frequencies, because it groups by TE+TEfrequency we obtain many rows in the end.

Comment: I've come up with this code to sum the different rows: ddply(filter_lt_10,.(TE),summarize,sum=sum(count_uniq_strain))